# Получение строки из ArrayList<Integer> и обратно . Чтение данных из документа.

Tags: java, динамические-массивы

В процессе работы приложения данные записываются в ArrayList . После эти данные сохраняются в документ и при новом запуске считываются из документа в тот же ArrayList. Есть статические методы decrypt(String encrypted) и encrypt(String cleartext) , которые расшифровывают и зашифровывают строку.

Так вот я не могу дать этот массив на шифровку, так как он не строковый. Да думаю и строковый массив тоже не годится так как это Объект. А нужна строка. Если запишу как строку , то не знаю как обратно прочесть в строку и из нее сделать ArrayList. Как быть ?

Comment: Используйте формат JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Преобразование `List<Integer> numbers` в строку

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
    if (i != 0)
        sb.append(", ");
    sb.append(numbers.get(i).toString());
}
String string = sb.toString();
```

Преобразование строки обратно в `numbers`

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
String[] strings = string.split(", ");
for(int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
    try {
        numbers.add(Integer.valueOf(strings[i]));
    } catch (NumberFormatException exc) {}
}
```

Comment: Это работает только на Api 24 + ? У меня SDk min установлен 14

Comment: Вам стоило указать, что вопрос относится к Android. Исправил.

Comment: Вместо List<Integer> могу нужный мне ArrayList<Integer>  использовать?

Comment: Конечно можете.

Comment: Я так понимаю тут String[] strings = string.split(", ");    string это та строка которая была создана при преобразовании в строку? тогда мне нужно будет   её объявить в конструкторе. У меня преобразование в строку в одном методе , а обратно уже в другом.

Comment: И откуда у Вас n2 ?

Comment: Это вам уже виднее. Можете сделать её полем какого-то класса, можете сделать локальной для метода и передавать в метод параметром или как нагрузку интента, а можно через bundle, или даже доставать из БД.

Answer (score 1):

Упаковка списка в строку:

```
public static String packNumbers(List<Integer> numbers)
{
    String str = numbers.toString();
    return str.substring(1, str.length() - 1);
}
```

Распаковка строки в список:

```
public static List<Integer> parseNumbers(String str)
{
    String[] strNumbers = str.split(", ");
    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (String strNumber : strNumbers)
    {
        numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(strNumber));
    }
    return numbers;
}
```

Код работает даже при использовании JDK 5.

Использование метода `toString` у списка (реализованного в классе `AbstractCollection`) для формирования можно считать не самым надёжным: а ну как когда-нибудь его переделают, начав использовать другой разделитель или убрав скобки, однако навряд ли это случится в обозримом будущем.

Если в метод `parseNumbers` передать невалидную строку, будет проброшено `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, мне подошел вариант ответа, что я выбрал правильным. Быть может Ваш ответ даже лучше, позже обязательно вникну в него, а сейчас нужно заняться другой частью программы.